# How can i create a calendar in html/css/js with the source being a calendar file (.ics)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, calendar

I'm quite new to stackoverflow so apologies if I don't form this question correctly but I'm trying to create a "clean" calendar widget for a website I'm working on. I have been provided with a calendar file to grab the calendar data from. I'm thinking of something like the image ive uploaded, but without the "Add event". The calendar will have my preloaded data from the file and the user will be able to simply view the data, maybe hover over it for a description? I'm using bootstrap to make everything look good. Are there any easy ways of doing this? Thanks! [the calendar i have in mind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4i6lE.png)

I can't really find any way of doing this.. i've searched for methods but cant find any that do what i need.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.